# get value from a array stored in database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a value stored in database from which i want to get value of a key of that array using mysql query . The value is

```
{"key":"754rtgsdsds?clientAccnum=940122","clientSubacc":"0005","eventType":"NewSaleSuccess","eventGroupType":"Subscription","accountingCurrency":"USD","accountingCurrencyCode":"840","accountingInitialPrice":"29.95","accountingRecurringPrice":"24.95","address1":"321 Hurley Street","billedCurrency":"USD","billedCurrencyCode":"840","billedInitialPrice":"29.95","billedRecurringPrice":"24.95","cardType":"MASTERCARD","city":"Cambridge","clientAccnum":"98989","country":"US","email":"sd","firstName":"David","formName":"201cc","initialPeriod":"30","ipAddress":"65.96.161.24","lastName":"Pendleton","nextRenewalDate":"2014-12-02","password":"mark3mark","paymentType":"CREDIT","postalCode":"02141","priceDescription":"29.95(USD) for 30 days then 24.95(USD) recurring every 30 days","rebills":"99","recurringPeriod":"30","referringUrl":"","reservationId":"02143067100090003425","state":"MA","subscriptionCurrency":"USD","subscriptionCurrencyCode":"840","subscriptionId":"021430670100000601309","subscriptionInitialPrice":"29.95","subscriptionRecurringPrice":"24.95","subscriptionTypeId":"00000001870","timestamp":"2014-11-02 10:46:09","transactionId":"0214306701000006013","username":"figofani","X-variableToPassNamesAsString":"clientAccnum:clientSubacc:formName:regionalPricingProfileId:regionalPricingList:","X-session":"fromBillingCascade","X-x_enc":"74d5d917b514206d3be4e000d9a5bee1","X-clientCascadeConfigurationId":"17159","X-region-option":"on","X-externalCascadeFlowId":"13967","X-previousCascadeProcessorId":"1","X-payment-option2":"on","X-previousCascadeProcessorName":"CCBill","X-billingCascade":"1","X-cascadeProcessorId":"1","X-emailConfirmationSessionId":"74d5d917b514206d3be4e000d9a5bee1","X-join":"JOIN","X-checkAns":"true","X-cascadeProcessorName":"CCBill","X-cascadeProcessorRoleId":"1","X-stage":"1","X-enc":"74d5d917b514206d3be4e000d9a5bee1","X-isRedirected":"false"}
```

and the value of key which i wanted is `subscriptionId` . Can this be done in mysql itself ? or do we need php for it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a JSON string representaion of an object, you will have to read the whole column and then decode the json string so you can process it easily in PHP

So assuming you read that column from the database and into a variable called $json_string;

```
$obj = json_decode($json_string);

echo $obj->subscriptionId;
```